# Finding the x, y coordinates of a moving object relative to the main screen

Tags: objective-c, coordinates

I have an object that is a subview of the main view. This object is moving across other subviews during its existence. I need to get the x, y-coordinates of the object frequently as it moves. I'm using an NSTimer with a 0.01 time interval to update the data however, I can only seem to get it to update the coordinates when it's not on another subview.

I've been trying to use:
    `[self.window convertPoint:point fromWindow:nil];`
and
    `[self.window convertPoint:point fromView:(the view the object exists on)]`

but this still only returns the coordinates when it's not over another subview. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the animation you will likely need to access the views layer and get the `presentationLayer` as the view won't return its true frame while the animation is in progress.